# how can I tell an activity for an Android app to resolve a symbol using a certain library?

Tags: android, libraries

I want to use the function JSch() in an activity, but Android Studio tells me "cannot resolve symbol JSch()". Library jsch-0.1.54.jar from the lib directory of android-studio contains a class "JSch.class". How can I tell my activity to use that JSch.class?

I have so far tried nothing. I do not know what to try

Comment: `import static com.package.JSch.JSch`

Comment: it looks like you are missing Java basics. Please take some basic lessons before you continue.

Comment: Give me a hint, please.

Comment: I tried import static com.package.JSch.JSch but Android studio underlines in red "package.JSch.JSch" with the comment "Unexpected token"